# Check global object availability

Tags: properties, groovy, gradle

Is there method to check in Groove availability of object in global scope? My script runs on dev machine and CI. When it runs on CI there is `teamcity` object but on dev not. Next method throws exception on dev machine.

```
def isTeamCityAvailable(){
    tc = this['teamcity']
    if(tc == null){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this in a gradle build script? try: `return hasProperty( 'teamcity' )`

Comment: @tim_yates yeah, it works, thanks! If you add answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in a `build.gradle` file, you should be able to do:

```
def isTeamCityAvailable() {
    hasProperty( 'teamcity' )
}
```